# UWP release build fails with internal compiler error

Tags: uwp

Well, in debug mode it works absolutely fine, but once built in release mode I get these errors:

```
1>  D:\Dev\RI.Vis\RI.Vis\obj\x64\Release\ilc\in\RI.Vis.exe
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38050,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38072,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38073,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38113,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38113,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Vector2')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38162,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38184,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38185,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38225,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38225,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Vector3')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38274,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38296,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38297,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38337,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38337,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Vector4')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38386,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38408,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38409,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38449,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38449,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Matrix3x2')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38498,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38520,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38521,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38561,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38561,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Matrix4x4')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38610,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38632,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38633,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38673,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38673,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Plane')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38722,42): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38744,155): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38745,125): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38785,31): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(38785,7): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Quaternion')
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83002,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83004,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83006,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83008,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83010,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83012,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(83014,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87543,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87544,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87545,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87546,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87547,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87548,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(87549,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88149,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88150,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88151,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88152,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88153,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88154,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(88155,137): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96411,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96412,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96413,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96414,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96415,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96416,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(96417,168): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98821,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98822,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98824,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98825,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98827,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98828,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98830,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98831,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98833,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98834,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98836,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98837,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98839,98): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(98840,166): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99487,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99488,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99489,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99490,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99491,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99492,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99493,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99494,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99495,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99496,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99497,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99498,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99499,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
1>  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\RI.Vis.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(99500,97): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

So obviously I added a NuGet reference to NetStandard.Library then. But it still fails with the same errors... I've looked up the issue and I barely find any information. At best some sketchy workarounds which don't seem to be a good solution (something about referencing manually some .Net Framework related .Net Standard libs which might cause issues later on).

Comment: What is your app's target version and min version?

Comment: Both the last major update (autumn I think).

Comment: You can right click your project and select the **Properties** to see it.

Comment: Both are set to the Fall Update, 16299.

Comment: You can try to delete the bin and obj file in your project to rebuild the project again.  Also a basic way is step by step to delete the reference dll and the corresponding code in the project to find witch one cause the issue.

Comment: Okay I'll try on Mondays, but that's not really what I expected using UWP... Will report back after I tried, thanks so far.